# How to iterate through window.localStorage

Tags: javascript, jasmine, local-storage

When I try to iterate over `window.localStorage` I don't appear to be getting any key/values I set returned.

Firstly I get undefined on `window.localStorage.length`.

I have a test setup that passes and behaves as expected, my issue is when I try to delete an item that begins with text and I have to iterate over `window.localStorage`.

I suspect I have something wrong with my spies.

I have 2 methods I want to test:

```
export function deleteItem() {
  const item = window.localStorage.getItem('myItem');
  console.log(item);
  // Logs out 12345 when running test 1

  if (item) {
    window.localStorage.removeItem('myItem');
  }
}

export function deletePrefixedItem() {
  let deleted = false;
  console.log(window.localStorage.length);
  // Prints out undefined when running test 2
  
  console.log(window.localStorage);
  // Prints out { getItem: [Function: getItem], setItem: [Function: setItem], removeItem: [Function: removeItem], clear: [Function: clear] }

  for (let i = 0; i < window.localStorage.length; i++) {
    const key = window.localStorage.key(i);
    if (key.startsWith("myItem") && key !== "myItem") {
      window.localStorage.removeItem(key);
      console.log(`Item with key '${key}' deleted from local storage.`);
      deleted = true;
    }
  }
  if (!deleted) {
    console.log(`No key starting with 'myItem' followed by random text found in local storage.`);
  }
}
```

Test 1 (passes fine and behaves as expected):

```
describe("deleteMyItem", () => {
  let store = {};
  let getItemSpy;
  let setItemSpy;
  let removeItemSpy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    getItemSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, "getItem").and.callFake((key) => {
      return store[key] || null;
    });

    setItemSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, "setItem").and.callFake(
      (key, value) => {
        store[key] = value.toString();
      }
    );

    removeItemSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, "removeItem").and.callFake(
      (key) => {
        delete store[key];
      }
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    store = {};
  });

  it("should delete myItem from local storage if it exists", () => {
    // Set the item
    window.localStorage.setItem("myItem", "12345");
    console.log(store);
    // Logs out { myItem: '12345' }

    deleteItem();

    // Expect removeItemSpy to have been called with 'myItem'
    expect(removeItemSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("myItem");

    // Expect fedID to have been deleted
    const item = window.localStorage.getItem("myItem");
    expect(item).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

Test 2 (fails):

```
describe("deletePrefixedItem", () => {
  let store;
  let getItemSpy;
  let setItemSpy;
  let removeItemSpy;

  beforeEach(() => {
    store = {}
    
    getItemSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, "getItem").and.callFake((key) => {
      return store[key] || null;
    });

    setItemSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, "setItem").and.callFake(
      (key, value) => { store[key] = value.toString();
    });

    removeItemSpy = spyOn(window.localStorage, "removeItem").and.callFake(
      (key) => {
        delete store[key];
      }
    );
  });

  afterEach(() => {
    store = {};
  });

  it("should delete a item from local storage if it exists", () => {
    // Set the item
    window.localStorage.setItem("myItem", "test");
    window.localStorage.setItem("myItem1234", "test");
    console.log(store);
    // Prints out { myItem: 'test', myItem1234: test }

    // Call deletePrefixedItem function
    deletePrefixedItem();

    expect(removeItemSpy).toHaveBeenCalledWith("myItem1234");

    const item = window.localStorage.getItem("myItem1234");
    expect(item).toBeNull();
  });
});
```

How can I iterate over `window.localStorage` and access the key/value pairs that are being set?

Answer (score 3):

Remember that localStorage is an object, so loop through it using **Object.entries**:

```
// Clear localStorage and then set 3 test entries
localStorage.clear();
['One','Two','Three'].forEach((x,i) => localStorage['key'+i] = x);

// Loop through localStorage entries
Object.entries(window.localStorage).forEach(([key,val]) => console.log(key,val));
```

B.t.w. using localStorage 'out of the box' is a hassle, mostly since it only stores strings and other values have to be serialized/deserialzied. You can write a small abstraction (if you're not too far into legacy code) and be done with all of that once and for all. See below - easyStorage works just like any object except that it is persistant/automatically stored in localStorage:

```
// easyStorage - an abstraction of localStorage
/*export*/ const easyStorage = (() => {
  let content = {};
  try { content = JSON.parse(localStorage.myOnlyKey); } catch (e) { }
  return new Proxy(content, {
    set(target, key, val) {
      target[key] = val;
      localStorage.myOnlyKey = JSON.stringify(content);
    },
    deleteProperty(target, key) {
      delete target[key];
      localStorage.myOnlyKey = JSON.stringify(content);
    }
  })
})();
```

Test it:

```
// Store anything that can be serialized to JSON
if (!easyStorage.someNames) {
  easyStorage.someNames = ['Anna', 'Bob', 'Cecilia'];
  easyStorage.someObject = { foo: 'bar' };
  console.log('setting/storing')
}

// and get it back
console.log(easyStorage.someNames);
console.log(easyStorage.someObject);
```

Comment: Thank you @ThomasFrank, that definitely helps and using your example above i can see `key0 One key1 Two key2 Three`. I put your sample code in my `deletePrefixItem` method and it set the key/values just fine...

It appears then that setting key/values in my test are not using the same storage?

Comment: I don't know about that - by amended my answer with my favorite way of using localStorage without any hassles.

Comment: That is not how you are supposed to use `localStorage`; at the very least, it is designed to be persistent, i.e., resilient to closing the tab, but those values are stored in RAM and are going to be lost.

Comment: No they are not going to be lost - trust me I have used this approach in a number of projects. Each time someone changes the easyStorage object (that is proxied) the change gets stored in localStorage. Why wouldn't you want to simplify the use of localStorage? Try out the code if you don't believe me :)

Comment: Okay, I’ve checked MDN, and `localStorage.key = value` is really the same as `localStorage.setItem(“key”, value)`. That’s surprising. (I’m going to ignore the “wouldn’t you want to simplify” question.)

Comment: Yes, people are using setItem and getItem a lot too - and that is totally unneccesary. But so is ever approaching localStorage bare hands if you want to use for anything else than storing strings. Just put an abstraction that is 14 lines of code in place and start using it as a 'normal' object that is persistant.